# Android GeoFence events not triggered/received (Testing GeoFences in general)

Tags: android, location, google-api-client, geofencing, android-geofence

I've been banging my head over this issue for longer than I feel comfortable to admit.

I can't get Android geofences to work. I've followed the official tutorial. I've double-checked every detail and I've read every meaningful article on the topic, back to page 3 of my Google queries.

I've isolated the geofencing logic out of my application so that I
   can concentrate fully on the matter. [Here's my code.](https://github.com/melon-android/geofence-test)

- I've tried using both an IntentService and BroadcastReceiver to
  capture the events.

  - I've declared them in the manifest.
- Any intent that comes through would be printed in the console (none
  so far).
- I'm using the up-to-date GoogleApiClient instead of LocationClient.
- I'm creating only one geofence and I'm verifying that everything is
  fine in the result callback.
- I'm asking for location permission on 6.0+ devices
- I've tried testing with mock location apps on physical. I've used

  - Lockito
  - com.lexa.fakegps
- I've tried testing with the official emulator
- I've tested using real location on a physical device

I'm probalby missing something fundamental here.

I've set the intial trigger in the to INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER in the GeofencingRequest.Builder. Should I receive a GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER the moment when I register the geofence?

Comment: Hi, 
I ran your code and the geofence are generated perfectly.

Comment: Hi there. Can you confirm you are receiving events? Is GeofenceTrasitionService#onHandleIntent(Intent) invoked?
If so, please describe your test scenario: device, os version, gps data (fake or real), etc.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: First off, to get the simple things that may cause your issues: Do you have location settings turned on? If so, is it high accuracy or Mobile/Wifi/Low power?

Comment: Is GeofenceTrasitionService#onHandleIntent(Intent) > YES
DEVICE> Samsung J5
Marshmallow
Real GPS